# Django Admin - Duplicating and Filtering Many to Many fields in form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin

I am kind of stuck...

This is the situation. I got a Match Model, a Player Model and a Team model.

Match has many to many relationship with Player (Player particiaptes in a match)
Match has a foreign field Home Team
Match has a foreign field Visitor Team
Team has a one to many relationship with Player

What I would like to do is when editing the match, be able to see 2 manytomany fields but filtered by teams. For example, the first manytomany field will only show players from the host team and the second manytomany field will only show players form the visitor team...

I have no idea where to start.... Really stuck...

Thanks a lot,
Ara

Comment: Can paste your sample code?

Comment: Hi, well except for my models I have basically just a fieldset right now to show my form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter a dropdown based on another dropdown in the same page without refreshing, then you will need some kind of AJAX functionality. Django admin will not support this out of the box.

But there are several third party applications which use JQuery or other Javascript libraries to achieve the sort of functionality you want. for e.g.:

- [Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)
- [Hierarchical Django AJAX Forms](https://github.com/dragonx/django-hier-ajax-form)

Comment: Hi, ok perfect! But I would need to have duplicate the fields and it's not letting me...

Comment: Hi, I tried Django Smart Selects but it only works if it's Foreign Key... I've done the same thing in PHP... I can just copy that code but I don't know, first of all, how to edit the form but only for this specific model ( and only to add a module underneath ). And how I can retrieve the values of the fields I plugged in...

Comment: Have a look at [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you where to start:

```
class Team (models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player,...)
    attribute1
    atribtue2
    atribute3


class Player (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='none', verbose_name=_(u'Player Name'))
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name = "")


class Match (models.Model)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_(u'Date'))
    attribute1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attribute2 = models.IntegerField(values)
    homeTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="Home Team")
    visitorTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name='Visitor Team')
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u'sitio web'), related_name=u'product_site')
```

Player and Match I show you how you could do the relations, foreignkeys and manytomanys, you could add a variable to player to store all played match... you have to create some atributes in match to store goals,faults,cards.....

I didn't try this code, but I think that could put you in good direction

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, My models are already done. I just need to show the players field in 2 different drop down filtered by the teams.... Sorry if it was not clear.